# Set the checkbox as checked by default at options page

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-options, settings-api

I'm making a theme settings page, so when I start coding the checkbox options, it works fine if the default value is `unchecked`. Here is the code:

```
function classy_show_resume_section_callback () {
    $options = get_option( 'classy_general_settings' );
    $html = "<label class='switch'>";

    if ( empty( $options['classy_show_resume'] ) ) $options['classy_show_resume'] = 0;

    $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='classy_general_settings[classy_show_resume]' value='1' " . checked($options['classy_show_resume'], 1, false) . " >";

    $html .= "<div class='slider round'></div>";
    $html .= "</label>";

    echo $html;
}
```

However, because I want the checkbox as `checked` by default, I had to change the `if` condition of the previous code. If it is empty, make the `$options` var equals to `1`. So the code will be:

```
function classy_show_resume_section_callback () {
    $options = get_option( 'classy_general_settings' );
    $html = "<label class='switch'>";

    if ( empty( $options['classy_show_resume'] ) ) $options['classy_show_resume'] = 1;

   $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='classy_general_settings[classy_show_resume]' value='1' " . checked($options['classy_show_resume'], 1, false) . " >";

   $html .= "<div class='slider round'></div>";
   $html .= "</label>";

   echo $html;
}
```

So it worked. The checkbox gets `checked` by default, but when I `unchecked` and clicked save, an issue happened in the database. It worked fine and the value was removed, but in the front end, because the if condition value now is empty, it appears on the screen as `checked` all the time, although in real it's not in the DB (conflict).

So how do I fix this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Option-1:* Change the option from `show` to `hide`:

The easiest way would be to change the naming and behaviour of the `option`. So instead of `$options['classy_show_resume']`, you may implement it as `$options['classy_hide_resume']`.

That way, by default `hide option` is **not checked**, that means you show it by default. Then hide it when this `hide option` is checked.

So simply by changing the name of the option, and then implementing `hide option` (instead of the `show option`) in your theme, you can fix it easily.

So your CODE will be like:

```
function classy_hide_resume_section_callback () {
    $options = get_option( 'classy_general_settings' );
    $html = "<label class='switch'>";

    if ( empty( $options['classy_hide_resume'] ) ) $options['classy_hide_resume'] = 0;

    $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='classy_general_settings[classy_hide_resume]' value='1' " . checked($options['classy_hide_resume'], 1, false) . " >";

    $html .= "<div class='slider round'></div>";
    $html .= "</label>";

    echo $html;
}
```

## *Option-2:* Make `classy_show_resume` checked by default:

If you must use `classy_show_resume` with default to checked, then you may use the following logic:

By default `get_option( 'classy_general_settings' )` should return `false` and when it's saved as `unchecked`, it'll either be an empty string or an  array with `$options['classy_show_resume']` not set. So we'll use this to determine the default value vs. saved `checked` or `unchecked` value.

According to this, your new CODE will be like:

```
function classy_hide_resume_section_callback () {
    $options = get_option( 'classy_general_settings' );
    $classy_show_resume = 0;
    if ( $options === false ) {
        // nothing is set, so apply the default here
        $classy_show_resume = 1;
    }
    else if( is_array( $options ) && isset( $options['classy_show_resume'] ) ) {
        // classy_show_resume is checked
        $classy_show_resume = $options['classy_show_resume'];
    }

    $html = "<label class='switch'>";

    $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='classy_general_settings[classy_show_resume]' value='1' " . checked( $classy_show_resume, 1, false ) . " >";

    $html .= "<div class='slider round'></div>";
    $html .= "</label>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Now it should be checked by default and show the correct `checked` | `unchecked` status after saving.

Comment: Thx for your comment :)
and actually, It's a very nice idea but I was hoped to know a solution to the conflict issue if it possible because the checkbox as defaults checked means the sections is shown so there're more options ( settings ) about this section it will be connected for this specific checkbox for examples if I unchecked it the other options ( settings ) will be uneditable as these options edits some content at the section and because now the sections is hidden I can't let the user makes any edit.

Comment: @heshamshawky Updated the answer, use ***Option-2*** if you need the  default `checked` option.

Comment: Thx a lot bro it's worked :) .